# How to convert a String to an Enumerated Data Type in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I have an enumerated data type that looks like such:

```
data MathExpr a = X
               | Coef a
               | Sum (MathExpr a) (MathExpr a)
               | Prod (MathExpr a) (MathExpr a)
               | Quot (MathExpr a) (MathExpr a)
               | Exp (MathExpr a)
               | Log (MathExpr a)
                 deriving (Eq,Show,Read)
```

I'm trying to convert a String to this type. I want to use the read function thats available within the prelude. To do so I created another function as such:

```
readMathExpr :: String -> MathExpr a
readMathExpr = read
```

This gives me an error while compiling saying that there is no instance for (Read a) arising from use of 'read'. If anybody could point me in the right direction or link a useful tutorial pertaining to the read function I'd be extremely grateful. Thank you !

Comment: Hint: what do you need to do to get the function `show' :: a -> String; show' = show` to compile? (Hint to hint: what is the signature to `show`? (Hint to hint to hint: GHCi has a `:t` command to look up the type of something, or alternatively [Hoogle will show it](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=show) to you.))

Comment: You may start with writing a `Read` type class instance for your `MathExpr a` type.

Comment: @Redu no need, GHC can derive that (and does already, in the OP).

Comment: It may be worth pointing out that you don't need to define a new function.  The expression `read "Sum (Coef 1) (Coef 2)" :: MathExpr Int` works directly, and when GHC can infer the type (which will usually be the case in a realistic program), you can drop the type annotation `:: MathExpr Int`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is simply that your proposed type signature is too general. The derived instance of `Read` for `MathExpr a` only works when there is already an instance of `Read` for `a`. That is, if you were to write out the instance yourself it would start:

```
instance (Read a) => Read (MathExpr a) where ...
```

I don't imagine that in practice you will wish to read values of type `MathExpr a` for types `a` which aren't themselves instances of `Read`, so the fix is simply to add the necessary type-class constraint to the signature:

```
readMathExpr :: (Read a) => String -> MathExpr a
readMathExpr = read
```